# allow access to www-data to files in user's home dir

Tags: permissions, apache2

I have 2 users with the following home directories:

- user1 --> /srv/user1
- user2 --> /srv/user2

**Problem is:**
I want these home folders to be accessible online via apache2 but accessible to the users as well .
If I set the owner of each home directory to the corresponding user,  I can ftp to these directories, but apache fails to access the files.
If I set owner to www-data, the directories work fine with apache, but the users can't read their own home directories.

If I add user1 and user2 to www-data group and give +rw to the entire group, this will make user 1 able to read user 2's files (and vice-versa), and I want each user to read his own files only.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have the time right now to look into this in detail, but [per-user web directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html) might be of interest.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck thanks the link. I heard about  the userdir module, but thought it might be an overkill for my use-case (only 2 users have web folders, the others are just local users). I  might give it a try in the future if needed, but the trick in the marked answer worked fine for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the other way round. Provide the `www-data` account access to the user files:

```
usermod -a -G users www-data
```

Comment: this does the job for me. I just had to make sure some files outside the web folder don't have rw for group and it worked fine. Thanks